# Why my key commands are not working

Tags: javascript, html

My issue is that my javascript is not seeing when i push my key down to move the object on the screen.
So here is my java script code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("maincanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var keys = [];

var width = 500,
  height = 400,
  speed = 3;

var player = {
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  width: 20,
  height: 20
};

window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  keys[e.keycode] = true;
}, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
  delete keys[e.keycode];
}, false);
/*
up - 38
down - 40
left - 37
right - 39
*/

function game() {
  update();
  render();
}

function update() {
  if (keys[38]) player.y -= speed;
  if (keys[40]) player.y += speed;
  if (keys[37]) player.x -= speed;
  if (keys[39]) player.x += speed;
}

function render() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100)

  context.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
}

setInterval(function () {
  game();
}, 1000 / 30);
```

if you can not tell i am very new to this and just learning the basics.

Comment: `e.keyCode` instead of `e.keycode`. In the future, you can easily figure this out by doing `console.log(e)` to see what properties are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you want out of the event object is called `keyCode`, not `keycode`:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("maincanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var keys = [];

var width = 500,
  height = 400,
  speed = 3;

var player = {
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  width: 20,
  height: 20
};

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  delete keys[e.keyCode];
}, false);
/*
up - 38
down - 40
left - 37
right - 39
*/

function game() {
  update();
  render();
}

function update() {
  if (keys[38]) player.y -= speed;
  if (keys[40]) player.y += speed;
  if (keys[37]) player.x -= speed;
  if (keys[39]) player.x += speed;
}

function render() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100)

  context.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
}

setInterval(function() {
  game();
}, 1000 / 30);
```

```html
<canvas id="maincanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: lolz thanks. its always the small things like capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue you might be running into is that `keys` is an array and you are treating it like an object. `keys[38]` is looking for a key at index `38` NOT a key with a value of `38`. Set `keys = {};`

**Edit** Never mind, I see you are just setting the index at 38. I would say it's a little bit of a weird approach, consider using an object rather than an array.